# Run VBA Macro after change

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to apply my macro below to a table of data and have it calculate for each one.

> Example: When user enters cells A1 and A2, the macro will run and
>   populate A3 & A4.
>
> A1: 80292
>
> A2: 11234
>
> A3: (MACRO RUNS AND RETURNS DISTANCE IN MILES)
>
> A4: (MACRO RUNS AND RETURNS COST FOR TRIP)

The Macro I made is below -- how would I apply it to my needs?

```
Public Sub GetValue()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim myPoints As String
    Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim objElement As Object

Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
sURL = "http://www.defensetravel.dod.mil/mobile/views/mileage/mileage.cfm"
With appIE
    .Navigate sURL
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

   appIE.Document.getElementById("from").Value = Range("A1")
   appIE.Document.getElementById("to").Value = Range("A2")
   appIE.Document.forms(0).submit

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
    Loop

    Dim miles
Set miles = appIE.Document.getElementsByName("miles")(0)
Dim milesText
milesText = miles.Value

    Range("A3").Value = milesText

Dim cost
Set cost = appIE.Document.getElementsByName("milescost")(0)
Dim costText
costText = cost.Value

    Range("A4").Value = costText


Set appIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You mean how do you change the hard-coded cell IDs to make this loop through every row in a table?

Comment: Sounds to me like you just want an event that fires `GetValue()` every time A2 is changed?

Comment: @Rup, yes that is correct. So lets say A1 & A2 is one group, then B1 and B2 is another. I am looking for it to go down the line until the last filled cell and update everything accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In standard module, change your code like that

```
Public Sub GetValue(x As Range, y As Range)
Dim ie As Object
Dim sURL As String
Dim myPoints As String
Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim objElement As Object

Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
sURL = "http://www.defensetravel.dod.mil/mobile/views/mileage/mileage.cfm"
With appIE
    .navigate sURL
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

appIE.document.getElementById("from").Value = x
appIE.document.getElementById("to").Value = y
appIE.document.forms(0).submit

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Dim miles
Set miles = appIE.document.getElementsByName("miles")(0)
Dim milesText
milesText = miles.Value

x.Offset(2).Value = milesText

Dim cost
Set cost = appIE.document.getElementsByName("milescost")(0)
Dim costText
costText = cost.Value

y.Offset(2).Value = costText
Set appIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Then in worksheet module try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Or Target.Address = "$A$2" Then Call GetValue(Range("A1"), Range("A2"))
If Target.Address = "$B$1" Or Target.Address = "$B$2" Then Call GetValue(Range("B1"), Range("B2"))
End Sub
```

Give this a try in worksheet module

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Row = 1 Or Target.Row = 2 Then
    If Target.Column >= 1 And Target.Column <= 150 Then
        Call GetValue(Cells(1, Target.Column), Cells(2, Target.Column))
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How can I use this to automate additional cells? (ie: B1 & B2, C1 & C2...etc)

Comment: @YasserKhalil: Why not just explain this as a UDF, don't need `_Change` event.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Great idea too

Comment: @YasserKhalil thank you. How can I apply this to larger groups of 150 or so sets?

Comment: Have a look at the updated post .. See if this suits you